# How to limit access to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a video on making a good javascript application infrastructure. Basically what it said was:

- Your application consists of components
- Components are parts of the page that can act on their own.
- components can be registered into te application.
- upon registration, they get their own sandbox.
- A sandbox is an component's interface to the application core.
- The core is built on top of a javascript library.
- Components only have access to their sandbox, not to other components, nore the core or the underlying library.

Now, what I'd like to make is an application where you can easily make new components. Components have their own part on tha page, their own div in which they can work. And here comes the first part of my question: I want to give these components a copy of the jQuery object, but that has an internal restriction applied so that it can only work inside a certain containing element.

The second part is,that even if a component has limited access to the DOM using jquery, it can still access the document. I have tried both setting Window and Document to null, before running my test script, but the browser doesn't allow this. Is there any way that I can truly restrict the possibilities of an object to the methods of 1 object that I pass to it?

Comment: You might want to watch that video juuuuust a couple more times.

Comment: I think I very well understood what the video was about, thank you. I'm just trying to expand on the idea of a sandbox, to give components not only their own scripting sandbox, but also in terms of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mis-understanding the point here.  The intention isn't "make it 100% imposible for a component to acces anything it shouldn't".  The ONLY way to do that is the insanely complicated step that Facebook took which is to parse the JS/HTML code and re-write it to dis-allow certain references, etc.  I'm betting it took their dev team 1,000+ hours to do and there are still holes in it.

Basically the intention is to give each component a sandbox to play with and then say "please only use this".  The authors then comply with the request.

Your sole other option is iFrames, in which case a component can do whatever it wants and it won't effect anything (assuming you're on a different sub-domain and you provide a parent-window proxy).

Comment: It's also worth noting that when the author refers to sandboxing, it isn't referring to a part of the HTML DOM but to part of the JavaScript code itself. The code in one component shouldn't be able to willy-nilly call a random function in another component without it being explicitly published.

Comment: I dunno, nothing wrong with sandboxing the DOM as well.  It's what I do -- say "here's a div, play nice"

Comment: Even in the frame, doesn't Javascript have access to the parent window via `top` ?

Comment: @Travis - hence my comment about being on a different domain/sub-domain.  If you're on a different sub-domain and the parent window doesn't explicitly set/clear document.domain, there's no way for the child window to get to it (unless the parent doesn't have a sub-domain, so 'www.' is preferred here)

Comment: "here's a div, play nice" (which is a good solution when using good design practice) doesn't _force_ other code to stay within that div. We're back to expecting good design practice as the solution rather than trying to artificially limit the creators beyond what the language allows.

Comment: Well that's what my entire post was about -- that attempting to enforce these constraints is next-to-impossible if you don't want to use an iFrame to do it.

Comment: If I don't get any other answers, I'll probably set this answer as the selected answer, so thx.

Oh, and btw, @Zimzat, I know that  the author didn't mean dom sandboxing. I just wanted to include one part of the dom as an interface for the sandbox.